# SqlCeBulkCopy smallint issues

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm using ErikEJ's SqlCeBulkCopy class and getting exceptions thrown when I'm inserting into a column whose destination is of type smallint. The IDataReader implementation I'm using holds every value as a string. I get an exception after the first smallint column's value is read, an InvalidCastException is thrown with the following stack trace:

> at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeUpdatableRecord.SetClrTypeValue(Int32
>   ordinal, Object value, String method) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeUpdatableRecord.SetValue(Int32 ordinal,
>   Object value) at
>   ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(ISqlCeBulkCopyInsertAdapter
>   adapter) at ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader
>   reader) at
>   MyApplication.Modules.Analysis.SqlCeFileConfiguration.SqlCeBulkDataStreamer.CopyFromReader(IDataReader
>   reader, String destinationConnectionString, String tableName) in
>   E:\Code\Desktop
>   MyApplication\software\desktop_and_web\MyApplication\MyApplication.Analysis\SqlCeFileConfiguration\SqlCeBulkDataStreamer.cs:line
>   44 at
>   MyApplication.Modules.Analysis.Services.SqlCeDataManagerService.InsertData(String
>   connectionString, String tempWorkFolder, TableInfo tableInfo) in
>   E:\Code\Desktop
>   MyApplication\software\desktop_and_web\MyApplication\MyApplication.Analysis\Services\SqlCeDataManagerService.cs:line
>   742

The first time this occurs during my process, the value is "8". It occurs when handling other tables too, always at a smallint and always when a perfectly valid string is being converted.

Can anyone suggest why this would occur and how I can work around it? Should my IDataReader implementation convert each type before returning it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to store smallint as smallint in your IDataReader! But feel free to upload a sample project, and I will have a look. Could you not simply use an IEnumerable, WriteToServer also supports that?

Comment: Thanks Erik, converting in the IDataReader worked. I didn't want to use an IEnumerable because I was reading from .dat files.